# Task.WaitAll is blocking indefinitely

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following class:

```
class MultiWebProgram
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string[] websites = new string[]
    {
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=one",
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=two",
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=three",
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=four"
    };

    Task<int>[] taskList = new Task<int>[websites.Length];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var website in websites)
    {
      taskList[i] = Task<int>.Run(() => GetSiteBytes(website));
      i++;
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskList);
  }

  public static int GetSiteBytes(string website)
  {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    var stream = client.OpenRead(new Uri(website));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int totalBytes = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
      bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
      totalBytes += bytesRead;
    }
    while (bytesRead >= 4096);
    Console.WriteLine("Got {0} bytes from {1}", totalBytes, website);
    return totalBytes;
  }
}
```

When I run this, the code blocks on the `WaitAll` command.

I tried changing the program to this:

```
class MultiWebProgram
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string[] websites = new string[]
    {
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=one",
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=two",
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=three",
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=four"
    };

    Task<int>[] taskList = new Task<int>[websites.Length];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var website in websites)
    {
      taskList[i] = GetSiteBytesAsync(website);
      i++;
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskList);
  }

  public async static Task<int> GetSiteBytesAsync(string website)
  {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(website));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int totalBytes = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
      bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4096);
      totalBytes += bytesRead;
    }
    while (bytesRead >= 4096);

    Console.WriteLine("Got {0} bytes from {1}", totalBytes, website);
    return totalBytes;
  }
}
```

In other words, I made the GetSiteBytes method async - but it made no difference.

One thing I did notice; when I started up Fiddler and ran either version of the program, there was no blocking.

What could be going on here?

** EDIT: **
The problem seemed to be the OpenRead method. When I used DownloadData/DownloadDataAsync, the blocking went away.

Comment: Task.WaitAll() will block indefinitely if one or more of the tasks fails to complete. So rather than asking why it blocks, you should be asking why one of the tasks fails to complete. But first you need to debug the process and identify the one that doesn't complete. In the end, it might just be that google.com doesn't appreciate four simultaneous requests from the same client (something that Fiddler might perturb enough to get things working). But without a better question, it will be hard to provide a solution.

Comment: When you say "indefinitely", how long did you wait? For me, the time is about 2 minutes.

Comment: Just some additional info, Google doesn't like screen scrapers and have many controls in place to prevent it. If you are testing with google.com, you will run into many issues. Its best to test on your own site.

Comment: I think that the problem is with the OpenRead / OpenReadTaskAsync call. After the call on the second task, any successive attempt to call this on the web client blocks. This happens, no matter what url I use. Is this a documented behaviour of OpenRead? Like I said earlier, the only time this goes away is when I use a proxy like Fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about closing the stream after reading all data. Try this and it will work:

```
using (var stream = client.OpenRead(new Uri(website)))
{
...
}
```

I'm not sure what *OpenRead* method does under the hood but I assume that it allocates some resources which are limited and you cannot use more than is available. Personally I always assume that if a method returns a stream, then I have to close it.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks, @michał-komorowski!